# react bootstrap width does not fit on mobile screen

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

[image]

What should I do to get rid of the white space at the right of the slider?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Nevermind. The solution was:

```
html: {
    over-flow: "hidden"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue with the white space to the right of the screen and I was not able to fully fix the issue using the CSS overflow solution. *I'm using React JS and Bootstrap 5*

This **did not work** (at first glance I thought it did):

```
html: {
over-flow: "hidden"}
```

What I noticed was that some of my code was packed with "rigid" "div" tags.

This is what I was experiencing (background red is to help me see what's happening to the <Container/Row/Col> when I resize):
[image: this is a view from Chrome Dev Tools]

This was my code:

```
<Col className=" bg-danger">
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center my-4">
            <div className="d-flex flex-column">
              <label
                className="fw-bold bg-dark bg-opacity-50"
                for="start-date"
              >
                Start Date (YYYY-MM-DD)
              </label>
              <input
                id="start-date"
                className="input-box"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Start date (YYYY-MM-DD)"
                value={startDate}
                onChange={(event) => setStartDate(event.target.value)}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div className="d-flex flex-column mx-2">
              <label
                className="fw-bold bg-dark bg-opacity-50"
                for="end-date"
              >
                End Date (YYYY-MM-DD)
              </label>
              <input
                id="end-date"
                className="input-box"
                type="text"
                placeholder="End date (YYYY-MM-DD)"
                value={endDate}
                onChange={(event) => setEndDate(event.target.value)}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center mt-4">
              <Button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-light mx-2"
                onClick={trigger}
              >
                Search
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Col>
```

I restructured my code by adding <ROW/COL>, see more examples here (https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns):

```
 <Row>
        <h3>Space Image Gallery - Content from... </h3>
        <Row className=" d-flex justify-content-center my-4 bg-danger">
          <Col sm lg="4" className="d-flex flex-column mx-2 my-1">
            <label
              className="fw-bold bg-dark bg-opacity-50"
              for="start-date"
            >
              Start Date (YYYY-MM-DD)
            </label>
            <input
              id="start-date"
              className="input-box"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Start date (YYYY-MM-DD)"
              value={startDate}
              onChange={(event) => setStartDate(event.target.value)}
            ></input>
          </Col>
          <Col sm lg="4" className="d-flex flex-column mx-2 my-1">
            <label className="fw-bold bg-dark bg-opacity-50" for="end-date">
              End Date (YYYY-MM-DD)
            </label>
            <input
              id="end-date"
              className="input-box"
              type="text"
              placeholder="End date (YYYY-MM-DD)"
              value={endDate}
              onChange={(event) => setEndDate(event.target.value)}
            ></input>
          </Col>
          <Col
            lg="2"
            className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center mt-4"
          >
            <Button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-light mx-2"
              onClick={trigger}
            >
              Search
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
```

This is the result!:
[image: this is a view from Chrome Dev Tools]